# Bazel rules and filegroup inconsistency

Tags: build, tensorflow, bazel

I created a filegroup rule to have in one label all the .proto files of a library.

```
filegroup(
    name = "protos_all_src",
    srcs = glob(
        ["**/*.proto"],
        exclude = [
            "protobuf/worker.proto",
            "protobuf/worker_service.proto",
            "protobuf/master.proto",
            "protobuf/master_service.proto",
        ],
    )  
)

tf_proto_library(
    name = "protos_all",
    srcs = ":protos_all_src",
    ),
...
)
```

but strangely with this format this other rule fails:

```
cc_library(
    name = "lib_internal",
    srcs = glob(
        [
            "lib/**/*.h",
            "lib/**/*.cc",
            "platform/*.h",
            "platform/*.cc",
        ] + tf_additional_lib_srcs(),
        exclude = [
            "**/*test*",
            "platform/**/cuda.h",
            "platform/**/stream_executor.h",
        ],
    ),
    hdrs = [
        "lib/core/blocking_counter.h",
        "lib/core/refcount.h",
        "lib/gtl/edit_distance.h",
        "lib/gtl/int_type.h",
        "lib/gtl/iterator_range.h",
        "lib/gtl/manual_constructor.h",
        "lib/gtl/top_n.h",
        "lib/io/iterator.h",
        "lib/io/match.h",
        "lib/jpeg/jpeg_handle.h",
        "lib/png/png_io.h",
        "lib/random/random.h",
        "lib/random/random_distributions.h",
        "lib/random/weighted_picker.h",
        "lib/strings/ordered_code.h",
        "lib/strings/proto_text_util.h",
        "lib/strings/regexp.h",
        "lib/strings/scanner.h",
        "lib/wav/wav_io.h",
        "platform/demangle.h",
        "platform/denormal.h",
        "platform/platform.h",
        "platform/tensor_coding.h",
        "platform/tracing.h",
    ],
    copts = tf_copts(),
    linkopts = ["-ldl"],
    deps = [
        ":protos_all_cc",
        "//tensorflow/core/platform/default/build_config:platformlib",
        "//third_party/eigen3",
    ],
)
```

note the protos_all_cc rule as a dep.

if I revert back to

```
tf_proto_library(
    name = "protos_all",
    srcs = glob(
        ["**/*.proto"],
        exclude = [
            "protobuf/worker.proto",
            "protobuf/worker_service.proto",
            "protobuf/master.proto",
            "protobuf/master_service.proto",
        ],
    ),
```

everything works fine.

I would expect that the first and the second format would be completely equal. What I am missing ?

EDIT:
The `tf_proto_library` is defined here:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/platform/default/build_config.bzl#L26

and the `cc_proto_library` is defined here:

https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/protobuf.bzl#L109

bazel version:

```
Build label: 0.2.3-homebrew
Build target: bazel-out/local-fastbuild/bin/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/BazelServer_deploy.jar
Build time: Tue May 17 15:07:52 2016 (1463497672)
Build timestamp: 1463497672
Build timestamp as int: 1463497672
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you paste your actual code and the error message you're getting?  It looks like there are several problems and I'm not sure which are copy-paste errors and which are code.

I'd guess the issue you're having is that you cannot list files (nor filegroups) as `deps` in a cc_library rule, and `":protos_all_cc"` is a filegroup.  `deps` must be other cc_libraries (it's "things this rule should link together"). But it's very hard to tell with out the error message nor definition of protos_all_cc.

Answer (score 0):

The `srcs` attribute should be a list, so your definition of `protos_all` should be

```
tf_proto_library(
    name = "protos_all",
    srcs = [":protos_all_src"], # note the list here
    ...
)
```

Maybe this is just a typo in the question, and the real problem is something else?
I get weird `Permission denied` problems when I try your `filegroup` approach.